# Why is Find not Found in my Repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, repository

In using this article as a guide [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations)
I'm trying to add a **GET** method to my Repository code that will return one "record" based on an **ID**. But the example code given:

```
public Product Get(int id)
{
    return products.Find(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

...when adapted to my class type:

```
public Platypus Get(int id)
{
    return platypi.Find(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

...won't compile because the "Find" is not found; and no "resolve" is available from the IDE's context menu, either.

The err msg on trying to compile is, `"HandheldServer.Models.Platypus does not contain a definition for 'Find'*"`

But why [sh,w]ould it? The corresponding class from the article has no Find method defined, either...???

Comment: There's not much connection with the linked article, this seems primarily an EF question (the 1 tag that's missing). If you want answers, put a little effort in the asking.

Comment: No, I'm not using EF. And, as I mention in my answer, this has been solved (and I marked it as such 3 hours ago).

Comment: It's still not about MVC or the Web API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial to which you linked, `products` is of type `List<Product>`.  And `List<T>` [does, in fact, have a Find()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

According to the error message you're seeing, `platypi` is of type `HandheldServer.Models.Platypus`, which appears to be a single instance of a model rather than a collection of that model.  Unless you define a `Find()` on your model, no single instance will have that method.  (Nor should it... there's really nothing to "find" in a single instance.)

In short, your `platypi` object should probably be a collection of `Platypus` object, not a single instance.  At least if it's in keeping with the repository implementation in that tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

In the sample code products is a `List<Product>`. `Find` is a standard [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on a generic collection.

Answer (score 0):

That was rather a dumb mistake on my part (I should have known better/been thinking more clearly). So this is what works:

```
public InventoryItem Get(int id)
{
    return inventoryItems.Find(i => 0 == (String.Compare(i.Id, id.ToString())));
}
```